# Can we get more office helpers for tex.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I think "Clippit" isn't enough we need at least the dog and the wizard too.

They should automatically answer the questions of the user by providing a natural conversation. I think [Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) might be a good start.

To demonstrate the Idea behind this, I'll show you a typical helper user interaction:

[image]

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127698/its-clip-cloppy

Comment: I thought this was only a tex.sx.com joke :D

Comment: Preferably this one: http://vigor.sourceforge.net/